# ReadXml method fails when xml file has attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, system.io.file

Working with this XML Sample
It will read and merge this file when there is no service attribute in elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Polling>
    <TimeStamp>6/7/2016 1:38:31 PM</TimeStamp>
    <successfulPackets>1</successfulPackets>
    <UnsuccessfulPackets>0</UnsuccessfulPackets>
    <ClientID>4af00c0d-51e0-44e4-8096-954b5f857948</ClientID>
    <Holder>Aetos-RemoteServices</Holder>
    <Nid>07987c6-c553-4033-b1ad-0ac63ac6f8fd</Nid>
    <Grid>8f85e55a-3928-4621-a9d6-69179e33bbd1</Grid>
    <Job>RemoteTestClient</Job>
    <DataPriv>1000000000</DataPriv>
    <DataUse>36</DataUse>
    <Clients>1</Clients>
  </Polling>
  <Polling>
    <TimeStamp>6/7/2016 1:38:13 PM</TimeStamp>
    <successfulPackets>1</successfulPackets>
    <UnsuccessfulPackets>0</UnsuccessfulPackets>
    <ClientID>4af00c0d-51e0-44e4-8096-954b5f857948</ClientID>
    <Holder>Aetos-RemoteServices</Holder>
    <Nid>07987c6-c553-4033-b1ad-0ac63ac6f8fd</Nid>
    <Grid>8f85e55a-3928-4621-a9d6-69179e33bbd1</Grid>
    <Job>RemoteTestClient</Job>
    <DataPriv>1000000000</DataPriv>
    <DataUse>36</DataUse>
    <Clients>1</Clients>
  </Polling>
</NewDataSet>
```

Non Working XML File Sample
  It will not read and merge these files but it will when there is no attribute

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <NewDataSet>
      <Polling>
        <TimeStamp service"1111">6/7/2016 1:38:31 PM</TimeStamp>
        <successfulPackets service"1111">1</successfulPackets>
        <UnsuccessfulPackets service"1111">0</UnsuccessfulPackets>
        <ClientID service"1111">4af00c0d-51e0-44e4-8096-954b5f857948</ClientID>
        <Holder service"1111">Aetos-RemoteServices</Holder>
        <Nid service"1111">07987c6-c553-4033-b1ad-0ac63ac6f8fd</Nid>
        <Grid service"1111">8f85e55a-3928-4621-a9d6-69179e33bbd1</Grid>
        <Job service"1111">RemoteTestClient</Job>
        <DataPriv service"1111">1000000000</DataPriv>
        <DataUse service"1111">36</DataUse>
        <Clients service"1111">1</Clients>
      </Polling>
   </NewDataSet>
```

The XML Desired Output

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <NewDataSet>
      <Polling>
        <TimeStamp service"1111">6/7/2016 1:38:31 PM</TimeStamp>
        <successfulPackets service"1111">1</successfulPackets>
        <UnsuccessfulPackets service"1111">0</UnsuccessfulPackets>
        <ClientID service"1111">4af00c0d-51e0-44e4-8096-954b5f857948</ClientID>
        <Holder service"1111">Aetos-RemoteServices</Holder>
        <Nid service"1111">07987c6-c553-4033-b1ad-0ac63ac6f8fd</Nid>
        <Grid service"1111">8f85e55a-3928-4621-a9d6-69179e33bbd1</Grid>
        <Job service"1111">RemoteTestClient</Job>
        <DataPriv service"1111">1000000000</DataPriv>
        <DataUse service"1111">36</DataUse>
        <Clients service"1111">1</Clients>
      </Polling>
      <Polling>
        <TimeStamp service"2222">6/7/2016 1:38:13 PM</TimeStamp>
        <successfulPackets service"2222">1</successfulPackets>
        <UnsuccessfulPackets service"2222">0</UnsuccessfulPackets>
        <ClientID service"2222">4af00c0d-51e0-44e4-8096-954b5f857948</ClientID>
        <Holder service"2222">Aetos-RemoteServices</Holder>
        <Nid service"2222">07987c6-c553-4033-b1ad-0ac63ac6f8fd</Nid>
        <Grid service"2222">8f85e55a-3928-4621-a9d6-69179e33bbd1</Grid>
        <Job service"2222">RemoteTestClient</Job>
        <DataPriv service"2222">1000000000</DataPriv>
        <DataUse service"2222">36</DataUse>
        <Clients service"2222">1</Clients>
      </Polling>
    </NewDataSet>
```

I am trying to read and merge xml file. it works with the xml files that do not have the attribute service="1111", but when I add an xml file with attributes service="1111" it will not work, it fails to read and merge from the Data sets.

```
string filename = @"C:\Users\srhea_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DashBoard\Server.Config\Polling\polling.xml";

// Reading and Writing Data for Merge: Also include current files from the xml in the data set by reading and current
// if the file exists, read 
// Modify the polling file
if (File.Exists(filename))
  {
      ReadMerge.ReadXml(filename); //This is a data set
      //Propergate the data by merging the current with the previouse loaded data
      ds.Merge(ReadMerge); //this is another dataset
      //Write XML after existing file and current data is merged into the new Dataset Scheme
      ds.WriteXml(filename);         
  }
  else
  {    
      //Just write xml data if the current file does not exist - Starts the polling file
      ds.WriteXml(filename);
  }
```

Comment: What's `ds` variable? What error do you have? You question is not clear and the code does not work to suggest a solution.

Comment: shouldn't xml attribute be in format `name="value"`? `service"1111"` is missing `=`

Comment: service="1111" is an attribute value for the entire segment of data elements in the xml file, the problem is the Data set Readmerge.ReadXml is not reading the file and  ds dataset.merge  method does not work when the xml file has attributes but if the attributes are removed it works.

Comment: I assume it is reading and writing the dataset but creating two data tables when you add the attribute and only creating one data table when you don't have the attribute.  The first tag in xml is the dataset name.  Next tag is the datatable name.  Next tag is column names followed by the rows of data.  Once you get past 4 level of tags the xml becomes fragmented so when you read the xml you get data that should be in one table scattered in multiple tables.

Comment: What it is supposed to do, is read an xml file then merge the current existing data with the new incoming data on the xml file, which works only when the xml file is not placing attributes. so if the xml has attributes I debugged it and it broke on the ReadMerge.ReadXML() but i removed the attributes and it worked I need to merge an xml file with attributes so i can filter the xml file into a report

Comment: Show us the desired output merged XML.